# How do I get UUENCODE to work?

Tags: rhel, email, utilities, rpm

I have a server that I have inherited that has an older version of Redhat installed due to software requirements and now there is a need to use UUENCODE to allow email attachments.  The `uuencode` and `uudecode` files are not in `/usr/bin`.  I tried copying them from another server but I receive an error:

> /lib64/tls/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.4' not found when we try to run it.

It appears that I may need to install the sharutils.rpm but I am not sure which one to download?  Can anyone either point me to the correct rpm to download or an alternative method for processing uuencode?

Server Details:

```
$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 2.6.9-42.ELsmp (bhcompile@ls20-bc1-13.build.redhat.com) (gcc version 3.4.6 20060404 (Red Hat 3.4.6-2)) #1 SMP Wed Jul 12 23:32:02 EDT 2006

$ cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux ES release 4 (Nahant Update 4)

$ uname -a
Linux <servername> 2.6.9-42.ELsmp #1 SMP Wed Jul 12 23:32:02 EDT 2006 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried using `yum` to access the the RHEL repositories and install the version of sharutils that matches your release?

```
$ yum update
$ yum install sharutils
```

CentOS packages are generally one-to-one equivalents to RHEL packages with branding removed. You could try manually downloading a package from them. It looks like you could get that package here:

```
$ wget http://mirror.rackspace.com/CentOS/4/apt/i386/RPMS.os/sharutils-4.2.1-22.2.i386.rpm
```

Comment: Thanks.  That package seems to solve the problem (pending the end users testing).  It won't let me upvote the answer for some reason so I want to say thanks!

Answer (score 6):

### How to get uuencode on Fedora 17 Linux

**Find out what provides for uuencode using yum:**

```
yum provides uuencode
```

**Read what yum tells you:**

```
sharutils-4.11.1-3.fc17.x86_64 : The GNU shar utilities for packaging 
                                 and unpackaging shell archives
Repo        : @updates
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/uuencode
```

Oh Look! 'sharutils' provides uuencode

**Install that:**

```
yum install sharutils
```

**You get this output:**

```
[root@defiant el]# yum install sharutils 
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * fedora: ftp.usf.edu
 * rpmfusion-free: mirror.hiwaay.net
 * rpmfusion-free-updates: mirror.hiwaay.net
 * rpmfusion-nonfree: mirror.hiwaay.net
 * rpmfusion-nonfree-updates: mirror.hiwaay.net
 * updates: mirror.hiwaay.net
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package sharutils.x86_64 0:4.11.1-3.fc17 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

====================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                                Arch                                                Version                                                      Repository                                            Size
====================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 sharutils                                              x86_64                                              4.11.1-3.fc17                                                updates                                              176 k

Transaction Summary
====================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Install  1 Package

Total download size: 176 k
Installed size: 612 k
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
sharutils-4.11.1-3.fc17.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                                                                           | 176 kB     00:00     
Running Transaction Check
Running Transaction Test
Transaction Test Succeeded
Running Transaction
  Installing : sharutils-4.11.1-3.fc17.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                                   1/1 
  Verifying  : sharutils-4.11.1-3.fc17.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                                   1/1 

Installed:
  sharutils.x86_64 0:4.11.1-3.fc17                                                                                                                                                                                                  

Complete!
```

**Then test to see if it works**

```
[root@defiant el]# which uuencode
/usr/bin/uuencode
[root@defiant el]# uuencode --version
uuencode (GNU sharutils) 4.11.1
```